# Laravel/Lumen API with Web and Mobile consumers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, api-design, lumen, lumen-5.4

I've been searching for an answer to this during hours and I cannot make a decision that makes sense to me.

Basically, I need to create a system that will have users, each user will be able to add multiple "profiles" and on each profile, they will have a to-do list.

So:

**User 1**

```
- Profile1
    * ToDo List
- Profile2
    * ToDo List
- Profile3
    * ToDo List
```

**User 2**

```
- Profile4
    * ToDo List
- Profile5
    * ToDo List
- Profile6
    * ToDo List
```

This app will be accessible from both web interface mobile app (It will really need to be a native mobile app due requirements). I don't need the web app to be a Single Page Application.

So, to me makes sense to create an API which has users, profiles, and todo lists as resources and each consumer (web app/mobile app) will make requests to create, read, update and delete these resources.

Should a use Lumen to build this API and then create two completely independent applications (API consumers) to interact with it?

Or is it better to use Laravel and build the system (that will include the API endpoints and the web app, probably built using Vuejs)?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining three or four different systems (api + web app + Android + iOS) does not really make sense for lone developers or small teams. If you can avoid it do so.

Maybe you should look into using turbolinks and Laravel?

This should enable you to have your app on several platforms with very little overhead. And if you are just one developer avoiding overhead is vital.

Check out Full stack radio [69: Hybrid Mobile Apps with Turbolinks and Laravel](http://www.fullstackradio.com/69) for an introduction.

Comment: In this case, maintaining the app won't be a problem. I'm looking for best practices that will allow more flexibility (add new features in the future, for example). Regarding the Mobile App, for this specific scenario, I will really need a native Android App because of the requirements of the project (The app will need to push notifications to the user alerting users about items in the Todo list and interact with other apps)